# Class level design for validation engine with 2 independent entities

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, class-diagram

I have a use case where there will be 3 kind of data

1. Business_Enrollment_Program (lets denote them with BEP_1, BEP_2 ...)
2. Validation_Rule (lets denote them with R1, R2 ...)
3. Transaction_Type (lets denote them TT_1, TT_2 ...). This is an entity class having some attributes. On these entities Validation_Rule need to be executed.

Transaction_Type entities will look something like

```
public TT_1 {
private Business_Enrollment_Program;
private COMMON_FIELD_1;
private COMMON_FIELD_2;
private TT_1_SPECIFIC_FIELD;
}

public TT_2 {
private Business_Enrollment_Program;
private COMMON_FIELD_1;
private COMMON_FIELD_2;
private TT_2_SPECIFIC_FIELD;
}
```

Now i have 2 requirement while executing Validation rules:

1. Set of Validation_Rule that need to be executed depends on the Transaction_Type and it's Business_Enrollment_Program. 
   That means for TT_1 enrolled under BEP_1 we might need to execute (R1,R2) rules but for TT_1 enrolled under BEP_2 we might need to execute (R1,R3) rules.
2. Behavior of rule will depend on Transaction_Type and it's Business_Enrollment_Program. That means for TT_1 enrolled under BEP_1 behavior of rule R1 might be different compared to TT_1 enrolled under BEP_2

For rules i can create a structure like below:

```
public interface Rule <T> {
    public boolean execute(T transactionType);
}

public class R1_For_TT_1 implements Rule<TT_1> {
    public boolean execute(TT_1 transactionType) {
       //Do something here
    }
}

public class R1_For_TT_2 implements Rule<TT_2> {
    public boolean execute(TT_2 transactionType) {
       //Do something here
    }
}
```

And i can execute the rules like below

```
public processTransaction(T transactioType) {
    private boolean result = true;
    if(t instanceof TT_1) {
        result = result && R1_For_TT_1.execute(t);
    }
    else if (t instanceof TT_2) {
        result = result && R1_For_TT_1.execute(t);
        result = result && R2_For_TT_1.execute(t);
    }

    if(result) {
     // Do something
    }
    else {
     // Do something else
    }
}
```

Issue with this approach is i am not meeting my 2nd requirement where i wanted behavior of rule to depend on Transaction_Type and it's Business_Enrollment_Program.

Any idea how can i arrange my classes and entities so that both of my requirements are fulfilled elegantly?

Comment: Your 2 requirements sound the same. Can you show a little bit more of the picture? I don't see where this returned `boolean` is used.

Comment: @4castle In first requirement i want to decide which rules should be executed. But in second requirement behavior of the same rule need to be varied. To support second requirement you can think of a rule validateTotalAmount. Now in case of entity TT_1 related to BEP_1 logic to validate totalAmount can be different compared to entity TT_1 related to BEP_2

Comment: Is it possible for any transaction type to be executed on any business program?

Comment: @4castle Yes, thats correct. There is no restriction on the association of transaction type to business program

Answer (score 0):

I would give every `BusinessEnrollmentProgram` a `Map<TransactionType, List<Rule>>` as a field, so that you can organize what `Rule` objects go with each `TransactionType`. It will make it easy to lookup which `Rule`s need to be executed.

So it would look something like this:

**BusinessEnrollmentProgram.java**

```
public class BusinessEnrollmentProgram {

    private Map<TransactionType, List<Rule>> transactions = new HashMap<>();

    public void processTransaction(TransactionType t) {
        List<Rule> rules = transactions.get(t);
        boolean result = true;
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            if (!rule.execute(t)) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (result) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

**TransactionType.java**

```
public class TransactionType {
    private COMMON_FIELD_1;
    private COMMON_FIELD_2;

    // override hashCode() & equals() here so it can be used as a HashMap key
}
```

Then make all of your transaction types `extend TransactionType`, and allow your `Map` to store all of the relationships for which `Rule` is aloud with which `TransactionType`. Each `BusinessEnrollmentProgram` should have a separate set of rules to draw from.

If you're finding that there are too many classes extending `Rule`, use [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) or [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) instead.